# Hover div to change another div is not working

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the button, the div does not change the color
of the book div.  I can't understand it.

```css
.book {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.button:hover .book {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  BOOK
</div>
<div class="button">
  BUTTON
</div>
```

Comment: You've attempted to use a descendant selector, but `.book` isn't inside `.button`. Also, there are no previous sibling selectors in CSS. You need to restructure or use JavaScript.

Comment: how to write it without javascript

Comment: You can't. That's the point.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with Javascript:

```js
function chbg(color) {
  document.getElementById('book').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<div id="book">Div book</div>
<div id="button" onmouseover="chbg('red')" onmouseout="chbg('white')">Div button</div>
```

Comment: Nice, but event handlers would be better than inline JavaScript.